# How to capture the parameter value by mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using Apache2.2.17 and am trying to redirect the URL like below with the same parameter value being preserved but having a different key name.

```
/aaa/bbb/ccc?oldkey=value  => /ddd?newkey=value
```

I'm trying some variations of RewriteRule like below but not successful.

```
RewriteRule /aaa/bbb/ccc?oldkey=(.*) /ddd?newkey=$1 [R,L]
```

Then I noticed that if I have the condition like below, only the last *path value* is preserved and parameter key/value are lost.

```
RewriteRule /aaa/bbb/(.*) /ddd?newkey=$1 [R,L]  ;This produces /ddd?newkey=ccc
```

So my question is,

Is there a way to capture the parameter value by using Apache mod_rewrite and how can I achieve that? (I can use mod_proxy too)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check what's in `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} oldkey=(.*)
RewriteRule .* /ddd?newkey=%1 [R,L]
```

Where `%1` is the first capture group from `RewriteCond` (called [RewriteCond backreference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)).

Answer (score 0):

If by "parameter value" you mean the querystring then you can append it to your rewrites by adding QSA to your command so you have [QSA,R,L]